after merging two dataframes, how to reassign row index?
I merged two dataframes but I want to re-sort the index so it has a sequentially larger row number by 1. So for example below, the 3162 should be 281, and so on...
278  2024-05-08 09:18:40.224469054 
279  2024-05-08 09:18:40.224786435 
280  2024-05-08 09:18:40.225303505  
3162 2024-05-08 09:18:40.236961521  
281  2024-05-08 09:18:40.242515680  
282  2024-05-08 09:18:40.242732668    

merged two dataframes, did not work as expected to get sorted row values

You can use RangeIndex -> df.index = pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=len(df)) + df.index.min()

You can use numpy.arange and add the min:
df.index = np.arange(len(df))+df.index.min()

Or:
min_idx = df.index.min()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.index += min_idx

Output:
                              date
278  2024-05-08 09:18:40.224469054
279  2024-05-08 09:18:40.224786435
280  2024-05-08 09:18:40.225303505
281  2024-05-08 09:18:40.236961521
282  2024-05-08 09:18:40.242515680
283  2024-05-08 09:18:40.242732668

